# django permissions: User should only see and edit "his" objects

Tags: django, django-models

I'm building an app to manage flats:

There are different administrations. Each administration has users. Every administrations owns properties and every property has 1 to n flats.

Sofar so good. That's more or less setup.

No comes the tricky part. The users of administration A should only be allowed to see properties and flats that their administration owns.

How would I best do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a ForeingKey relationship between the Administrator model and the User model, you can right a filter on what the user can see. For example:

```py
class UserCreatesAndViewsSomething(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserLog (or something like that)
    template_name = 'some template you have'
    fields = ('field you want to display',)

# This function will submit the form to the database
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # this will help you determine what the current administrator is
        administrator = AdministratorModel.objects.get(user=self.request.user, administrator=self.kwargs['administrator'])
        form.instance.user = self.request.user

        # This will autopopulate administrator input to the current user administrator
        form.instance.administrator = administrator
        return super(UserCreatesAndViewsSomething, self).form_valid(form)

# get_context_data will help you determine what the user can see. 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                administrator = AdministratorModel.objects.get(user=self.request.user, administrator=self.kwargs['administrator'])
        context = super(UserCreatesAndViewsSomething, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['something'] = to_journal_entry.objects.filter(user=self.request.user, administrator=administrator)
        return context
```

I know that's a lot, but if you are at all familiar with Django you can certainly do it. You will have to go through some trial and error, but this is the approach I used for my project.

Finale note, this assumes all your users and user inputs are in the same database and the code helps you get only the relevant information. If you are dealing with high importance clients or or some sensitive information you should probably look into multi tenancy, which will set up a different schema or a different database for each of your clients. This will lead a different code structure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. Multi tenancy thing might be something worth considering, even though it might not be as flexible and dynamic it would definitely be more secure.

Comment: @rapsli Would you consider making this answer correct and upvoting it? Thanks in advance.